# Desviación Estandar en Python con Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Tengo un conjunto de datos llamado "Proceso" y tengo que sacar la `Desviación Estandar` de la columna proceso del DataSet

```
import pandas as pd
proceso = pd.read_excel("./Proceso.xlsx", sheet_name="Proceso")
proceso.head(19)
```

y los datos de salida del `.head(19)`

```
index  proceso
0      8.65
1     24.53
2     13.25
3      9.84
4      4.03
5      4.55
6     14.31
7      4.54
8      8.57
9      4.72
10     3.95
11    23.56
12     7.41
13     1.86
14    11.78
15     1.49
16     1.89
17    10.98
18     7.10
19    18.99
Name: proceso, dtype: float64
```

y mi problema es que no se con cual función de pandas se calcula la desviación estandar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hay dos métodos que permiten obtener la desviación típica o estándar en Pandas, uno pertenece a la clase `DataFrame`([`pandas.DataFrame.std`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.std.html)) y el otro a `Series` ([`pandas.Series.std`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.std.html)):

Ambos métodos tienen lo siguientes parámetros, muchos comunes a otros métodos similares como `mean`, `max`, `min`, `sum`, etc:

- **`axis`** : debe ser un entero, **0** para calcular la desviación estándar por columnas, **1** para calcularla por cada fila (index). Por defecto se calcula por columnas.
- **`skipna`** : booleano, **`False`** para que se tengan en cuenta los valores nulos, **`True`** para descartarlos.
- **`level`** : calcular a partir de un determinado nivel si tenemos un `MultiIndex`, debe ser un entero o una cadena con el nombre del índice (nivel). Es `None` por defecto.
- **`ddof`** : entero, especifica el incremento de los grados de libertad, por defecto es 1. Los grados de libertad (denominador) serán por tanto `N - ddof`, dónde `N` representa el número de elementos.

En el caso de `pandas.DataFrame.std` se implementa otro parámetro extra:

- **`numeric_only`** : booleano o `None`. Si es **`True`** solo se usarán las columnas que tengan como tipo `float`, `int` o `bool`. Si es **`False`** se fuerza al uso de todas, lo que puede causar una excepción si los tipos son incompatibles (`Datetime` + int, `float` + `str`(`object`), etc). Si se usa **`None`** (por defecto) se intentan usar todas las columnas en el cálculo, de no ser posible se descartan.

No se implementa en `pandas.Series.std` porque no tiene sentido al ser sus datos de un solo tipo.

Algunos ejemplos:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np

>>> data = {"A": (8.65, 24.53, 13.25, np.NaN, 4.03, 4.55, 14.31, 4.54, 8.57, 4.72),
            "B":  pd.timedelta_range('1s', periods=10),
            "C": (3, 12, 13, 4, 5, 7, 9, np.NaN, 17, 19)
            }

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)

>>> df
       A               B     C
0   8.65 0 days 00:00:01   3.0
1  24.53 1 days 00:00:01  12.0
2  13.25 2 days 00:00:01  13.0
3    NaN 3 days 00:00:01   4.0
4   4.03 4 days 00:00:01   5.0
5   4.55 5 days 00:00:01   7.0
6  14.31 6 days 00:00:01   9.0
7   4.54 7 days 00:00:01   NaN
8   8.57 8 days 00:00:01  17.0
9   4.72 9 days 00:00:01  19.0

>>> df.std(axis=1)     
0     3.995153
1     8.860048
2     0.176777
3          NaN
4     0.685894
5     1.732412
6     3.754737
7          NaN
8     5.960910
9    10.097485

>>> df.std()
A                   6.76626
B    3 days 00:39:48.990594
C                   5.73246


>>> df.std(numeric_only=True)
A    6.766256
C    5.732461


>>> df.std(skipna=False)
A                      NaT
B   3 days 00:39:48.990594
C                      NaT


>>> df.std(ddof=3)
A                     7.813
B    3 days 10:23:34.034924
C                   6.61928


>>> df["A"].std()
6.76626
```

Como en este último ejemplo, en tu caso basta con que hagas:

```
std = proceso["proceso"].std()
```

Al usarlo sobre una columna usas implícitamente `pandas.Series.std`.