# Funciones estadísticas. Misma función resultados diferentes en pandas, scipy y python statistics

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Dispongo del dataframe "tabla" siguiente:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
0   75  28  74  76  38  82  28  90  51  54  64  61  48  70  59  52  84  45  60  30
1   49  54  87  18  66  63  56  23  59  100 69  59  24  33  61  15  29  33  75  74
2   45  66  41  51  87  49  63  41  51  35  95  53  40  22  29  76  34  19  48  75
3   60  69  73  75  60  56  52  74  88  38  66  30  49  56  45  59  79  61  67  27
```

La preparamos para los cálculos previstos, de la siguente manera.

```
import pandas as pd

# Ordenación de los datos
datos = np.sort(tabla, axis=None)
lista_valores = tabla.values.tolist()
lista_ordenada = np.sort(tabla, axis=None)
# Create ndArray from a list
array_datos_ordenados = np.array(lista_ordenada.reshape(4,20))
# Generamos el dataframe valores
valores =  pd.DataFrame(lista_ordenada)
valores.columns = (["Valores"])
valores_ordenados = pd.DataFrame(array_datos_ordenados)
```

Sirviéndome de estas tablas y listas, calculo diversos indicadores de la estadística descriptiva, utilizando las funciones equivalentes de pandas, numpy y python statistics. Observo la siguientes diferencias en algunos resultados, por ejemplo.
**Desviación estádard.**

```
# Con pandas. Cálculo sobre una columna
valores["Valores"].std()
```

Devuelve 19.925494133288044

```
# Con pandas. Cálculo sobre una serie
lista_ordenada.std()
```

Devuelve 19.80056817366613

```
# Desviación estádard
import numpy as np
np.std(lista_ordenada)
```

Devuelve 19.80056817366613

**Varianza**

```
# Con pandas. Cálculo sobre una columna
valores["Valores"].var()
```

Devuelve 397.0253164556962

```
import statistics as st
st.variance(lista_ordenada)
```

Devuelve 397

```
import numpy as np
np.var(lista_ordenada)
```

Devuelve 392.0625
¿Cuál puede ser la razón de estas diferencias, y cual de estas opciones debemos considerar más exacta?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dices:

```
# Con pandas. Cálculo sobre una serie
lista_ordenada.std()
# 19.80056817366613
```

pero ese cálculo no usa pandas, pues `lista_ordenada` fue creada con `numpy`. Este cálculo usa por tanto `numpy` y por eso sale lo mismo que:

```
# Desviación estándard
import numpy as np
np.std(lista_ordenada)
# 19.80056817366613
```

¿Por qué no sale lo mismo que

```
# Con pandas. Cálculo sobre una columna
valores["Valores"].std()
# 19.925494133288044
```

? En realidad pandas por debajo usa `numpy` para hacer sus cálculos, el problema es que [`numpy.std()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html) admite un parámetro opcional llamado `ddof` que es la corrección a aplicarle al denominador, que por defecto vale `0`, pero cuando pandas invoca esta función le pasa en ese parámetro un 1. Si hacemos lo mismo, saldrá igual:

```
# Desviación estándard
import numpy as np
np.std(lista_ordenada, ddof=1)
# 19.925494133288044
```

Lo mismo ocurre con la varianza.

Esta corrección debe aplicarse (es decir, pasarle `1` como hace pandas) cuando la cantidad de datos es pequeña.

Answer (score 3):

Primero aclarar que `valores["Valores"]` es una Serie (una columna de un DataFrame no deja de ser una Serie). Por su parte `lista_ordenada` es un array NumPy, por lo que `np.std(lista_ordenada)` es lo mismo que `lista_ordenada.std()`

No hay ninguna discrepancia de exactitud entre Pandas y NumPy, la diferencia se debe a que [Pandas por defecto usa un grado de libertad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/191740/desviaci%C3%B3n-estandar-en-python-con-pandas/191750#191750) al calcular la varianza, usando como denominador `n - 1`, mientra que [NumPy por defecto usa 0 grados de libertad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html), usando como denominador `n` directamente (dónde `n` es es el tamaño de la muestra). Esto está determinado por el argumento `ddof` y es lo que se conoce como [corrección de Bessel](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correcci%C3%B3n_de_Bessel).

Es decir, la fórmula para calcular la varianza por defecto en NumPy sería:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mientras que Pandas por defecto usa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es importante cuando  **se quiere estimar la desviación estándar como indicador estadístico de una población a partir de una muestra de la misma**. NumPy por tanto proporciona por defecto una estimación sesgada de la varianza poblacional (sin la corrección de Bessel) mientra que Pandas proporciona una estimación no sesgada de la varianza de una población infinita hipotética (con la corrección de Bessel).

Si quieres conseguir el mismo resultado que en NumPy simplemente modifica el parámetro `ddof`, que acepta tanto `pandas.Series.var()`/`pandas.Series.std()`como `numpy.var()`/`numpy.std()` en función de si quieres o no corregir la estimación (`ddof = 1` -> corrección de Bessel (estimación no segada), `ddof = 0` -> Sin corrección (estimación sesgada):

> ```
> >>> valores["Valores"].std()        # pd.Series.std (valores["Valores"].std(ddof=1))
> 19.925494133288044
> >>> lista_ordenada.std(ddof=1)      # np.std
> 19.925494133288044
>
> >>> valores["Valores"].var()        # pd.Series.var (valores["Valores"].var(ddof=1))
> 397.0253164556962
> >>> lista_ordenada.var(ddof=1)      # np.var
> 397.0253164556962
>
> >>> valores["Valores"].std(ddof=0)  # pd.Series.std 
> 19.80056817366613
> >>> lista_ordenada.std()            # np.std (lista_ordenada.std(ddof=0))
> 19.80056817366613
>
> >>> valores["Valores"].var(ddof=0)  # pd.Series.var
> 392.0625
> >>> lista_ordenada.var()            # np.var (lista_ordenada.var(ddof=0))
> 392.0625
> ```

El módulo de la std `statistics`, al igual que Pandas, usa la corrección de Bessel tanto en `statistics.variance` (varianza muestral) como en `statitics.std (`desviación estándar muestral). En ambos casos no existe una forma directa de modificar esto como ocurre con NumPy/Pandas.

Por otro lado `statistics` proporciona también las funciones `statistics.pstdev` (desviación estándar poblacional) y `statistics.pvariance` (varianza poblacional) que obviamente usan `N` y no `n - 1` como sus homólogas muestrales.

---

### Edición

Hay una aparente discrepancia entre NumPy/Pandas (con `ddof` 1) y `statistics.variance` / `statistics.std`:

> ```
> >>> lista_ordenada.std(ddof=1)
> 397.0253164556962
> >>> st.variance(lista_ordenada)
> 397
> ```

Investigando un poco he dado con la causa, no está relacionado con la precisión, es solo un efecto colateral de la [función final](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/statistics.py) encargada de convertir el tipo de dato regresado por las distintas funciones de `statistics`:

```
def _convert(value, T):
    """Convert value to given numeric type T."""
    if type(value) is T:
        # This covers the cases where T is Fraction, or where value is
        # a NAN or INF (Decimal or float).
        return value
    if issubclass(T, int) and value.denominator != 1:
        T = float
    try:
        return T(value)
    except TypeError:
        if issubclass(T, Decimal):
            return T(value.numerator)/T(value.denominator)
        else:
            raise
```

Como los datos originales son de tipo `np.int64` a causa del `return T(value)` (dónde `T` es el tipo), se hace un casting a `np.int64` lo cual trunca el resultado eliminado los decimales. `T` no se modifica en el condicional porque **`numpy.int64` no es una subclase de `int`**  (tipo de Python estándar), por lo que en el `try` la línea `return T(value)` queda como `np.int64(value)` . Realmente `statistics` no está pensada explícitamente  para ser usada con tipos de NumPy sino con los tipos de Python estándar (`int`, `float`, `Decimal` y `Fraction`) por lo que nos podemos encontrar con este tipo de cosas, pero podemos resolver el problema de varias formas:

- Casting a `int` o `float` previo:

  > ```
  > >>> st.variance(int(n) for n in lista_ordenada)
  > 397.0253164556962
  >
  > >>> st.variance(map(float, lista_ordenada))
  > 397.0253164556962
  > ```
- Hacer que el array original sea de tipo `numpy.float`:

  > ```
  > >>> st.variance(np.array(lista_ordenada, dtype=np.float64))
  > 397.0253164556962
  > ```

No obstante si estamos usando numpy/pandas se deben usar sus funciones ya que permiten vectorizar las operaciones.

Answer (score 1):

Me había quedado con la duda de para qué servía el parámetro "ddof". Encontré  esta explicación que me parece conveniente aportar.
Para calcular, por ejemplo, la varianza y la desviación estándar de un conjunto de datos, utilizamos los métodos x.std() y x.var(). En las fórmulas de la varianza y de la desviación estándard, se asume por defecto  que el conjunto de datos es la población completa. Sin embargo, para cambiar este comportamiento, podemos usar el argumento ddof (grados de libertad delta). El denominador en la fórmula de la varianza es el número de elementos en la matriz menos ddof, por lo que para calcular la estimación imparcial de la varianza y la desviación estándar de una muestra,  necesitamos establecer ddof = 1